# Which of the conditions failed (how to detect which failed) in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, logging

I have the following `if`:

```
if condition_1 and condition2 and (condition3 or condition4):
   do something...
```

I want to detect which condition failed (what condition is `False` and write it to the log for further analysis.
How can I do this in Python 3?

Comment: Technically, there is only a single condition, and it failed. Do the condition_1 parts have side effects? Can you change this code so the if statement doesn't work quite like that?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a possible solution and sharing it with others:

```
conditions_dict = {"condition_name_1": [put your condition here, for example x < 5, the result should be True or False],
"condition_name_2": [put your condition here, for example x < 5, the result should be True or False], ...
}

    list_of_failed_conditions = [i for i in conditions_dict if not conditions_dict[i]]

    if len(list_of_failed_conditions) == 0:
        return True
    else:
        [log_function(err_msg) for err_msg in ["Condition failed: " + i for i in list_of_failed_conditions]]
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be using something like a decision table:

```
decision_table = {
(0, 1): error_msg_1,
(1, 0): error_msg_2,
(0, 0): error_msg_1, #in case you want to give priority to one error message
}
```

Then, to access each error message depending on the conditions that failed:

```
error_msg_for_logger = decision_table.get((condition_1, condition_2), "") #Return an empty string in case all conditions succeeded and there are no error messages
log_function(error_msg_for_logger)
```

So in case both conditions succeeded (that is, `(1, 1)` scenario), there will be no error message displayed. If you wanted to show a successful message, then you can add that in the decision table with a key `(1, 1)` and a value `successful_msg`, so you'd have something like: `(1, 1): successful_msg`.

Another simpler and in my opinion more readable way is to have a function that checks the condition and returns a message error depending on which condition failed, something like this:

```
def validate_conditions(condition_1, condition_2):
        if not condition_1:
            error_msg = error_msg_for_condition_1
            return (False, error_msg) #Don't return if you want to have error messages for all of the failed conditions.
        elif not condition_2:#Change for an "if" if you want to have error messages for all of the failed conditions, otherwise, if you want to show only one, then use "elif".
            error_msg = error_msg_for_condition_2 #Or += "\n" + error_msg_for_condition_2 if you want to keep adding the error messages and show them in different lines.
            return (False, error_msg)
        return (True, None)
```

Then, in the code that calls validate_conditions:

```
conditions_succeeded, error_msg = validate_conditions(condition_1, condition_2)
if not conditions_succeeded: #You could also just return the error_msg and not use a tuple at all, but I personally prefer it this way for readability purposes.
    log_function(error_msg)
```

Of course, this is just an example and there's a lot more you can do depending on your specific situation, for example, if you have many more conditions (like 5, 10 or more), you can split them in several functions like the one above and pass the `error_msg` as part of an object/list (so changes to `error_msg` are preserved if you want to keep adding message errors and not show only one), or you could also include all conditions in an object that contains them. If you were checking whether an user has access to a part of your application for example, you could pass an `User` object and perform all the validations passing just that `User` object instead of passing `condition_1, condition_2, condition_3`, etc.

Also, to complement your solution and in case you want to show the user which condition didn't succeed (for example, user is inactive at the moment of the action, or the user doesn't have sufficient admin permissions, etc.), the key in `conditions_dict` can be the error message to display.

Or, if you wanted to have the condition name as a key so that it's easier to read and understand, then you could use a tuple as the value, in which the first value is the condition, and the second value is the error message, so in `list_of_failed_conditions`, you'd have `i[1]` instead of `i` and `if not conditions_dict[i][0]` instead of `if not conditions_dict[i]`.

Additionally, just for the sake of completion and giving more ideas, you can remove the if/else block, and add just these two lines:

```
[log_function(err_msg) for err_msg in ["Condition failed: " + i for i in list_of_failed_conditions]]
return len(list_of_failed_conditions) == 0
```

This way, if there are no messages to log, the `log_function` line won't run (and won't throw any exception either) and the function will return `True` if the len of `list_of_failed_conditions` is 0, or `False` if it's not, so the same behavior remains. It may be a bit harder to read for some, but I at least find it simpler (if you wanted to take it even further, you could just return `not len(list_of_failed_conditions)`, without comparing it to 0, since in Python integer values have associated boolean values, so 0 is treated as `False` and any other number is treated as `True`, but at this point I think that is taking it too far).

It all depends on your specific circumstances, but I still wanted to post different options here so it can help more people in different situations.